# How can I change the orientation of a picture in the printer menu?

Tags: printing

In the printer menu I can change the orientation, but that only rotates the paper not the image on the paper. How can I rotate the image itself?

I already tried rotating the image itself, but that did not help. It still wants to print the image with the wrong orientation.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch off Auto Rotate / Automatisch drehen

You may need to then adjust the Scale to fit the page better - it may depend on whether the entire actual page content is visible.